# Curve extrusion without self intersection

Tags: modeling, scripting, bezier-curves

In the attached image is a cactus made from extruding a curve profile along another curve. Notice the self intersections at areas of sharp curvature. In animation this might not be a problem but for 3d printing, all self intersections must be removed so the resulting mesh is manifold. This is laborious for a single object and time prohibitive for hundreds of perceptually generated cacti.  **Is there a way to auto remove self intersects in this particular case?** I know no such tool exists but is there a good way of scripting this? If the mesh is broken into sub-meshes at all regions of intersection, the smaller manifold  submeshes should have their normals flipped if they belong to an intersection region and they should have a volume smaller than the target mesh.

[image: Cactus problem]

Comment: Best way to prevent this is to guarantee the curvature radius is never smaller than the bevel object dimensions. Other than that, there really is no way, besides manual fixing, as far as I know. 2d curves may be slightly better at preventing certain self intersections

Comment: Also try to increase the U Resolution of the Curves to have more vertices to work with